# fire in every five seconds with libGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

how do call fire method in every five seconds with libGdx ?

this is my Enemy class :

I wrote the following code, but it is wrong.

```
public class Enemy {

    private List<Bullet> bullets;
    private boolean isFire;

    public Enemy(){
        bullets=new ArrayList<Bullet>();
    }
    public void update(float delta) {
        Gdx.app.log("State", "State Fire");
        if(!isFire){
            Gdx.app.log("State", "Fire");
            fire();
        }else{
            Gdx.app.log("State", "No Fire");
        }
    }
    private void fire() {
        isFire=true;
        bullets.add(new Bullet(5, 32));
        Timer.schedule(new Task(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                reload();
            }
        }, getDelay());
    }
    private void reload(){
        isFire=false;
    }
    private int getDelay() {
        return 5;
    }
    public List<Bullet> getBullets(){
        return bullets;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve the problem? I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions for that:

1) the render method gets executed in every X milliseconds. You can use that one.

**__UPDATE__**

Below code is [from here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html)

```
void render(float delta)

Called when the screen should render itself.

Parameters:
    delta - The time in seconds since the last render.
```

in that method, you can add delta to figure out if it has been X milliseconds since the last time you did whatever you want to do. If so, you can do it again. If not just increment your counter. Here is what I mean.

```
double counter = 0;

void render(float delta){

   if (counter >= 5.0){
       counter = 0.0;
       fireUpYourTimelyProcessHere();
   } else {
       counter = counter + delta;
   }

  ... 

   // other rendering stuff

}
```

**However** Do not do things that take a long time to finish here, like making an HTTP request or something. 
}

2) Or you can create start a regular thread and start it. But keep in mind to avoid any UI rendering on that thread.

Comment: Please more explain the solution 1